# Not able to call method after typecasting to base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, box2d, cocos2d-x

I have `Ball` class which is derived from `PhysicsObject` class. In the following method I am getting a `Ball` instance from a `void` pointer and checking if its of type `PhysicsObject`. When I call the `collidingWith` method, it is not being called in the `Ball` class object. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
I have added an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) at the bottom. Please refer that.

**CODE**

```
void Levels::BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {
    b2Fixture *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    void *objA = fixtureA->GetUserData();
    void *objB = fixtureB->GetUserData();

    PhysicsObject* physicsObjA = reinterpret_cast<PhysicsObject*>(objA);
    PhysicsObject* physicsObjB = reinterpret_cast<PhysicsObject*>(objB);
    if ((physicsObjA != 0) && (physicsObjB != 0)) {
        physicsObjA->collidingWith(physicsObjB);    //not working
        physicsObjB->collidingWith(physicsObjA);
    }
}
```

**PHYSICSOBJECT**

```
#ifndef PHYSICSOBJECT_H_
#define PHYSICSOBJECT_H_

class PhysicsObject {
public:
    PhysicsObject();
    virtual ~PhysicsObject();

    virtual void collidingWith(PhysicsObject *obj) = 0;
};

#endif /* PHYSICSOBJECT_H_ */
```

**Ball.h**

```
#ifndef BALL_H_
#define BALL_H_

#include "Box2D/Box2d.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "PhysicsObject.h"

class Ball : public PhysicsObject {
public:
    //other methods
    void collidingWith(PhysicsObject *obj);
};

#endif /* BALL_H_ */
```

**Ball.cpp**

```
void Ball::collidingWith(PhysicsObject *obj) {
    CCLOG("Ball::collidingWith"); //this method is not being called
}
 //other methods

Ball::Ball() {
    //other code
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.userData = this;
    //other code
}
```

**UPDATE**
I have 3-4 other classes which are being derived from `PhysicsObject` just like `Ball`, those I havent mentioned here, but the common code is same.

**UPDATE SSCCE**

In `main.cpp` 's `foo()` getting error at `baseObjA->collidingWith(baseObjA);`

**Base Class**

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base(void);
    virtual ~Base(void);
    virtual void collidingWith(Base *obj) = 0;
};
```

**Another Base Class**

```
class AnotherBase
{
public:
    AnotherBase(void);
    ~AnotherBase(void);
    virtual void foo();
};
```

**Derived Class Header**

```
#include "Base.h"
#include "AnotherBase.h"
class Derived :
    public AnotherBase, Base
{
public:
    Derived(void);
    ~Derived(void);
    void collidingWith(Base *obj);
};
```

**Derived Class Implementation**

```
#include "Derived.h"

void Derived::collidingWith(Base *obj) {
    printf("Ball::collidingWith");
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Derived.h"

void myFoo(void* userData);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Derived *derived = new Derived();
    void* userData = derived;
    myFoo(userData);
    return 0;
}

void myFoo(void* userData) 
{
    Base* baseObjA = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(userData); 
    if (baseObjA != 0) {
        baseObjA->collidingWith(baseObjA);// Error here
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting to `Ball`?

Comment: @AdriC.S. No I havent, Actually I need it this way because there are other classes like `Ball` which are deriving from `PhysicsObject`

Comment: How do you know it's a `Ball`? Where does the ball come from? You may have sliced it if you've assigned a `Ball` to a `PhysicsObject`.

Comment: Can you produce a [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `GetUserData()` calls actually return a pointer to `PhysicsObject`?

Comment: Something is quite wrong here - and I don't mean "the code doesn't work". Why on earth are you hiding the type of the object by making it into a "void *". The whole point of using objects and virtual functions is that you can use it easily. You should have a function that returns the physicsobject from the fixture, not return a void *.

Comment: @PeterWood I created a scce and it ran successfully. Im thinking the problem is in some other part of the code.

Comment: @Angew I have debugged the code in visual studio and it shows the ball object correctly.

Comment: @asloob What does `correctly` mean?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I am using the Box2D library for adding physics in the game. The library has provided for a `void *userData` to store the game object's info which I can retrieve anytime later.

Comment: @PeterWood I can see the Object's fields and its values while debugging.

Comment: @asloob If you've sliced it, or are casting the wrong object type, it could look correct, but the virtual function tables will be wrong.

Comment: @PeterWood I am kind of sure that I am not casting the wrong object type. But how can I avoid slicing in this situation ?

Comment: @PeterWood I have added an SSCCE with another base class. Now I am getting error in the sscce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting from void* in box2d gave me very similar problems as well.

It seems like the `reinterpret_cast` causes the error, as `collidingWith` is a virtual method. (If the method is not virtual you should be able to call it without problems).

I've fixed mine doing this:

```
void* data; // You know it's type is Base

Base* base = static_cast<Base*>(data);
Derived* derived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(base);

derived->collidingWith();
```

Comment: Could you please vote this up? I'll add more explanation if you need it :)